# Memory leaks when I do log out

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting memory leaks when I'm using this library.

I would like know how can remove them when I did log out.
I guess that I must access inside this.notificationDOMRef and remove them but I dont know.

This is the library:[REACT-NOTIFICATIONS](https://teodosii.github.io/react-notifications-component/)

And in componentWillUnmount I do this:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    this.notificationDOMRef.current = undefined;
    this.notificationDOMRef = undefined;
};
```

And where I create component I do this:

```
{ this.state.showMapList ? <MapList /> : null }
```

EDIT

```
import React from "react";
import ReactNotification from "react-notifications-component";

class Notifiaction extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.notificationDOMRef = React.createRef();
  }

  addNotification = () => {
    this.notificationDOMRef.current.addNotification({
      title: "Awesomeness",
      message: "Awesome Notifications!",
      type: "success",
      insert: "top",
      container: "top-right",
      animationIn: ["animated", "fadeIn"],
      animationOut: ["animated", "fadeOut"],
      dismiss: { duration: 2000 },
      dismissable: { click: true }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app-content">
        <ReactNotification ref={this.notificationDOMRef} />
        <button onClick={this.addNotification} className="btn btn-primary">
          Add Awesome Notification
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Notifiaction;
```

Comment: can you show how you are adding the notifications?

Comment: I'm a little distracted by the fact that your class is named and exported with what appears to be a typo `Notifiaction` instead of `Notification`.  Mind if we clean that up?

Comment: No, feel free to do everything